# problems receiveing sms with twilio

Tags: arduino, twilio, sms, sensors, send

I code using arduino Yun, and , I got the following error message when trying to send sms to my phone.

"a threshold exceeded error has occurred - you have exceeded the threshold of 0 choreos per month configured."

Any idea why this error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

The first step of the node configuration is Twilio authentication. There are several components:

- The Twilio Account SID (required)
- Authentication Method (required):
  Auth Token: Authenticate with Twilio account Auth Token and
  API Key: Authenticate with Twilio API Key.
  [See more here](https://docs.losant.com/workflows/outputs/twilio/)